# Exclude current post from "Other posts of same category" loop

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I use this code to display other posts of same category in my page:

```
<?php 
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category();
$ceker=false;

foreach ($categories as $category) {
if ($ceker == false){
$ceker=true;    
?>
<h3 class="naslovostalih">Ostali članci iz ove kategorije:</h3>
<ul class="clanciostalih">
<?php

$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 10, 
    'offset'=> 1, 
    'category' => $category->term_id, 
    'exclude' => $post->ID
    );
}

$posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($posts as $pz) { ?>
        <li>
            <?php
            $title = $pz->post_title;
            $link = get_permalink($pz->ID);
            printf('<a class="linkpost" title="%s" href="%s">%s</a>', $title, $link, $title);
            the_post_thumbnail('thumb-232');
            echo '<div id="excerptcu">';
            echo excerpt(25);
            echo '</div>';
            ?>
            <p class="more-link-wrapper2"><a href="<?php $link; ?>" class="read-more     button"><?php _e( 'Opširnije &raquo;', 'fearless' ); ?></a></p>
        </li>

    <?php } // end foreach ?>
</ul>
```

How can I exclude current post that a client is viewing from query, so it doesn't display in "Other posts from this category" list?

Many thanks!

Comment: Where does this "Other posts from this category" come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a param "`exclude`" with [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

```
$args = array( 
    'numberposts' => 10, 'offset'=> 1, 
    'category' => $category->term_id, 
    'exclude' => $post->ID
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Use another variable in your `foreach()` loop because it's ambiguous with global `$post`

**Edit**

```
<?php 
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category();
$ceker=false;

foreach ($categories as $category) {
if ($ceker == false){
    $ceker=true;    
    ?>
    <h3 class="naslovostalih">Ostali članci iz ove kategorije:</h3>
    <ul class="clanciostalih">
    <?php

    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 10, 
        'offset'=> 1, 
        'category' => $category->term_id, 
        'exclude' => $post->ID
    );

    $posts = get_posts($args);
        foreach($posts as $pz) { ?>
            <li>
                <?php
                $title = $pz->post_title;
                $link = get_permalink($pz->ID);
                printf('<a class="linkpost" title="%s" href="%s">%s</a>', $title, $link, $title);
                echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pz->ID, 'thumbnail');
                echo '<div id="excerptcu">';
                echo substr($pz->post_content, 0, 25);
                echo '</div>';
                ?>
                <p class="more-link-wrapper2"><a href="<?php $link; ?>" class="read-more     button"><?php _e( 'Opširnije &raquo;', 'fearless' ); ?></a></p>
            </li>
        <?php } // end foreach ?>
    </ul>
<?php } // end if 
} //end foreach
```

?>

Comment: Thx for your reply, this looks good. How can I get current $post->ID ? Can you plz write the whole code, that will work in you oppion? Many many, thx!

Comment: `$post->ID` returns the current post ID . That's why I asked you to use another variable in your foreach loop
Example : `foreach($posts as $p)` instead of `foreach($posts as $post)`

Comment: I've edited the code as you instructed, but now, it doesnt work at all. Did I made an error? (you can see the code at the top)

Comment: because your `get_posts` params were not wrapped by `array()`.
Also, to get title in your foreach, you should do like this : `$pz->post_title`

Comment: I copy - pasted your edited code, but still no luck :(. I will check it again. I think there is a problem with  $title = $pz->post_title;

Comment: Open wp-config.php and set `WP_DEBUG` value to true

Comment: Add another `}` at the end the code. The first foreach is not closed

Comment: Ah! Because the excerpt show the current post content. See my edit

Comment: Okay, one more thing and it's all good. The permalinks? It gets the permalinks of the current viewing post and not the other post from that category. Any idea? p.s. Many, many thx for your effort.

Comment: Normally, it should work with `$link = get_permalink($pz->ID);`

Comment: All good. Its solved. Many thx. Btw, when I define with echo substr($pz->post_content, 0, 25);, I get 25 characters not 25 words. Any tip on how to make it 25 words, not characters? thx again. Marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `continue` to skip the loop of current category. Compare the selected category's id in the loop and skip the loop.